# What does the phrase "level them up" mean here?

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Here is a sentence from a combat game:

> If the player wins battles, she collects yellow slime which she can
>   dump on her favourite characters to **level them up**.

I am not sure about the meaning of the phrase "level them up" here. Does it simply mean that the character gets advantage in terms of ammunition, speed, etc. or does the phrase have a specific idiomatic meaning that I am not aware of?

Comment: Maybe this is the wrong site to inquire about "yellow slime" and  "character gets advantage in terms of ammunition, speed, etc." ... _level_  means to put all on an even playing field, normally.

Answer (score 4):

"Level up" is [a gaming term meaning to reach the next level](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/level_up), either of the game or the character. Levelling up a character generally brings new or improved abilities. Reaching the next level of a game brings new areas to play in or a greater degree of difficulty.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the term "level up" means to improve or advance in some way. I'm not sure, but I think the term originates from role-playing games where your avatar starts at level 1 and you do things/quests/challenges to "level up" to level 2 or higher.

References:

Forum post demonstrating real-world natural language use:
https://techraptor.net/content/playing-roles-etymology-rpgs

A book using the term in the title (read the book or find your own summary):
https://www.wired.com/2011/05/the-secret-origins-of-level-up/

Scroll down to "path of exile":
https://www.pcgamer.com/best-rpgs-of-all-time/

Saving the worst for last:
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/level_up